# Array to string conversion exception on DateField placeholder attr

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a form with a DateField like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('started', 'date', [
            'label' => 'Début',
            'placeholder' => 'ex: 01/09/2007',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'attr' => [
               'autocomplete' => 'off',
             ],
        ]);
}
```

And when I want to view it in a page, I have an exception occurs:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 322.

In logs, I have this details:

> at Twig_Template ->displayBlock ('widget_attributes', array('value' => object(ExperienceWork), 'attr' => array('autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => array('year' => 'ex: 01/09/2007', 'month' => 'ex: 01/09/2007', 'day' => 'ex: 01/09/2007'),[...]

I think Twig can not resolve array placeholder, but in [DateType.php source](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php) I found that this behaviour can not be avoid. I think I make somethings wrong, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I use an old version of symfony, but I have override the `setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)` with a custom date field object to avoid to return an array in placeholder field, like that:

```
$placeholderDefault = function (Options $options) {
    return $options['required'] ? null : '';
};

$placeholderNormalizer = function (Options $options, $placeholder) use ($placeholderDefault) {
    if (is_array($placeholder)) {
        $default = $placeholderDefault($options);

        return array_merge(
            array('year' => $default, 'month' => $default, 'day' => $default),
            $placeholder
        );
    }

    return $placeholder;
};

$resolver->setNormalizers(array(
    'empty_value' => $placeholderNormalizer,
    'placeholder' => $placeholderNormalizer,
));
```

The only thing I have replaced is the default return in $placeholderNormalizer function.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're looking to add an HTML5 placeholder, this is not how you do it. You'd add it via the attr array.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#attr

If not:

Looks like your form is expecting an array for placeholder, not a string.

Docs:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#placeholder

You could re-write your element as:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('started', 'date', [
            'label' => 'Début',
            'placeholder' => array(
               'year' => '2007', 'month' => '09', 'day' => '01'
            ),
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            'attr' => [
               'autocomplete' => 'off',
             ],
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not work, I have a `Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 322` and placeholder is send as an array.